# UWP no Element Content or Text when Binding with x:Bind

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, designer, xbind

I am very new to UWP and binding, but I believe I am figuring it out and making progress.  However, I am unsure if I am doing something wrong when using x:bind in design mode.  When I bind to my View Model, it works perfectly when the application is running, but when in design mode the element content, be it TextBlock text, Button text, etc., goes to empty.  This makes designing very difficult as I don't know where everything actually is on the page and the element sizes tend to go down to nothing, so they can hardly be clicked on or moved.

Microsoft says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/displaying-data-in-the-designer) "...But if you're using {x:Bind} then your bindings at least show placeholder values on the design surface (even for items controls), so you don't have quite the same need for sample data."  But I don't get any placeholder data for anything.

Here is a typical line for an element:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ItemCountLabel" Text="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.ItemCountText, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

I have tried a few things to make something work, like using Fallback value, but I can't seem to find a way of having placeholder text.  Is there such a thing?  Am I doing something wrong? Or is this just the way it is.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It seems odd to me encapsulating some of your attributes inside Text. Maybe just extract them in the outermost scope - like where the other attributes like "x:Name" are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP no Element Content or Text when Binding with x:Bind

I'm afraid you can't display design data with [x:Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension), Because x:Bind doesn't support design-time data. And the binding objects created by `{x:Bind}` and `{Binding}` are largely functionally equivalent. But `{x:Bind}` executes special-purpose code, which it generates at compile-time that means `FallbackValue`(*Specifies a value to display when the source or path cannot be resolved.*) property can't forecast if the binding path is
resolved.

For the scenario, We suggest use `Binding` and `FallbackValue` in design time like the following.

```
<TextBlock Foreground="Red" x:Name="ItemCountLabel" Text="{Binding ItemCountText,FallbackValue='Test Value', Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: Well, using {Binding} with 'FallbackValue' does indeed work and shows info at design time.  Now I need to decide if I want to go back though all my code and change or not.   Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed my old question sitting here and remembered I easily solved this a while back. Just for completeness, when using x:Bind a good solution is to be sure to include:

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
```

in the XAML page header, then my subject example can be called as such:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ItemCountLabel" d:Text="Sample Text Here" Text="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.ItemCountText, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```